# How to localize MMC snap-in (default actions, file menu, etc)

Tags: localization, internationalization, mmc, snap-in

I am developing a MMC 3.0 snap-in and have a framework in place to localize all string literals at run-time.

However, the MMC inserts lots of 'default' menu items, actions and descriptions, none of which I can access programmatically. For example, the "Refresh" & "Help" buttons.

Can anyone suggest a way of accessing these items in code, in order to translate their properties?

Comment: Per my knowledge it can't be done. Theoretically you can obtain window handle and update the controls, but I don't think it is legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the UI elements managed by MMC itself are localized according to whatever rules govern the UI language used in other parts of Windows. So if you install a French language pack and make it the default, I would assume that the basic MMC UI elements would then appear in French.